# How to enable the PHP DOM extension?

Tags: ubuntu, php

I have a server that has PHP 7.4.3 installed, but it doesn't load PHP-DOM.

It's not listed in `php -m` or `php -i`, nor when I load PHP on a page.

Here's what I tried so far:

1. Ran `sudo apt-get install php-xml` several times, it installs without a problem and shows the newest version is already installed.
2. Ran `sudo apt-get install php7.4-xml`, it's unable to locate the package.
3. Added `extension=dom.so` to php.ini and checked for the `--disable-dom` flag (not found).
4. Restarted apache multiple times throughout this process.

How can I enable the PHP DOM extension?

Comment: check this https://serverfault.com/questions/66189/how-to-enable-dom-without-recompiling-php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045478/how-do-i-enable-the-dom-extension-in-the-php-ini

Comment: Thanks @BlockchainOffice, I've tried those but it does not work

Comment: can you try install php7.0-xml & php7.0-mbstring instead of php-xml and check if this works?

Comment: Thank you. Tried that, still does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Run this command: `php7.4 -m`. Also make sure there is a file `dom.ini` in this folder: `/etc/php/7.4/mods-available/`
When on linux to enable the extenstion you should not edit the php.ini but use the command `phpenmod`

Also try installing PHP from `ppa:ondrej/php`.

For detailed steps read the comment by `karel`

Comment: `php7.4 -m` displays the loaded PHP modules, including extensions like `dom`. If `dom` is not listed in `php7.4 -m` 1. This suggests the DOM extension is not installed. You can install with `sudo apt install php7.4-xml`. 2. Once installed, you might still need to enable the extension in your php.ini file. Look for the `extension=dom.so` line and remove the leading `;` if it's present. 3. Restart your server to enable the changes.